# RelativeLayout - TextView not showing

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, listactivity, android-relativelayout

I've got a ListActivity which populates a list view using the following xml for each item.

Can anyone please tell me why the third row by the name of time window is not shown?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100dip"
android:padding="6dip" android:id="@+id/result_item" android:background="#000000">

<TextView android:id="@+id/rule" android:layout_marginLeft="55dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgview" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="bottom" android:text="Rule....." />

<TextView android:id="@+id/accuracy" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip" android:layout_below="@+id/rule"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/rule" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="top" android:text="Accuracy" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/time_window" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip" android:layout_below="@+id/accuracy"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/rule" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="top" android:text="time window..." />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgmine" android:layout_width="38px"
    android:layout_height="38px" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/mine" />
      </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second view is taking all the height space: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. Remove that statement and it will fix the issue.

By the way, it's highly recommended to use the `hierarchyviewer` too that is in the Android SDK. It allows you to see how the views are built and detect this kind of errors.

Comment: so alignParentBottom only has to be for the last view? if that's the case then it solved my problem :-) Cheers!